# Merge many tsv files by common key using Python pandas

Tags: python, merge, pandas, csv

I have several hundred tsv files with two fields, a common key and a unique sample id:

```
==> test1.vmat <==
CHROM:POS:REF:ALT  144-93-02
1:14653:C:T  1
1:14677:G:A  1
1:14907:A:G  1

==> test2.vmat <==
CHROM:POS:REF:ALT  144-93-01
1:14653:C:T  1
1:14522:G:A  1
1:14907:A:G  1
```

I would like to perform an outer join on all of the files using the field "CHR:POS:REF:ALT" to form one giant matrix. Example for two files:

```
CHROM:POS:REF:ALT  144-93-02    144-93-01
1:14653:C:T  1.0 1.0
1:14522:G:A  NA 1.0
1:14677:G:A  1.0 NA
1:14907:A:G  1.0 1.0
```

I got the output above using the following code, but I am having trouble looping over the hundreds of *tsv files in the directory (path/to/testN.vmat).  how can I modify this into something that will merge all the individual *tsv files from a directory into a single tsv file?

```
variant_field = "CHROM:POS:REF:ALT"
outfile = "everyone.vmat"

df1 = pandas.read_csv("path/to/test1.vmat", sep='\t', parse_dates=False)
df2 = pandas.read_csv("path/to/test2.vmat", sep='\t', parse_dates=False)

df3 = pandas.merge(df1,df2,on=variant_field, how='outer')
df3.to_csv(str(outfile), sep="\t", header=True, index=False, na_rep="NA", engine='python')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the 'CHROM:POS:REF:ALT' the *index* you join multiple frames:

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv("path/to/test1.vmat", sep='\t', parse_dates=False,
                                            index_col='CHROM:POS:REF:ALT')


In [11]: df1.join([df2], how='outer')
Out[11]: 
             144-93-02  144-93-01
1:14522:G:A        NaN          1
1:14653:C:T          1          1
1:14677:G:A          1        NaN
1:14907:A:G          1          1
```

In someways it's more honest to think of this as a concat rather than a join:

```
In [12]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[12]: 
             144-93-02  144-93-01
1:14522:G:A        NaN          1
1:14653:C:T          1          1
1:14677:G:A          1        NaN
1:14907:A:G          1          1
```

You can iterate through all the files using [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
from glob import iglob
pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, ...) for f in glob.iglob(*.vmat)), axis=1)
```

Comment: interesting, what do you mean by "more honest to think of this as a concat"?  I always thought of concatenating as just stacking the two matrices on top of each other

Comment: @alexhli good question, I say because each "frame" is really just a column in the final result, rather than a more complex merge (where several columns are coming from each frame)... subjective thing to say though!